Solving the quaternion sum of four squares/reduced norm
Let $K$ be an algebraic totally real number field,
and let $O_K$ its ring of integers
denote by $Q$ the quaternion algebra over $K$
I am looking for  references on the resolution  of the  reduced norm equation:
given $a$ to find $x+iy+jz+kt \in Q$ such that $x,y,z$ and $t$ are algebraic integers in $O_K$ and  $$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 +t^2 = a$$

What do you mean?  You want to algorithmically find (some? all?) solutions?  You want to know when there is a solution?  How many?

finding some if not possible to retrieve all solutions

for my purpose
I know that such a  solution  exists, I want to know if there is  a polynomial time algorithm to get all solutions and if not possible some of the   solutions
